# Create histogram from struct

Tags: struct, histogram, octave

I have a structure in Octave (v5.1.0), which looks like this:

```
>> cal_data
cal_data =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    OG_0100 =

        0.045260  -62.422000    0.044310  -60.768600
        0.045000  -61.576600    0.044620  -61.303400

    OG_0101 =

        0.044950  -61.316900    0.044110  -59.609500
        0.045150  -62.235500    0.044380  -61.260800

    OG_0102 =

        0.045160  -61.609900    0.044550  -61.759800
        0.044950  -61.725800    0.044480  -61.062300
```

etc... with fields named incrementally up to `OG_0280`. Each field is identical and consists of a 2x4 array of doubles.

I would like to create a histogram for each of the 8 values across all the fields in the struct and am getting stuck.

I have tried the following, to no avail:

```
>> hist([cal_data])

error: hist: Y must be real-valued
error: called from
    hist at line 90 column 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each of your struct elements is the same size, it would be more efficient and flexible to store them as a single 3D array. This code converts your current structure to such an array:

```matlab
cal_data.OG_0100 = [
        0.045260  -62.422000    0.044310  -60.768600
        0.045000  -61.576600    0.044620  -61.303400];
cal_data.OG_0101 = [
        0.044950  -61.316900    0.044110  -59.609500
        0.045150  -62.235500    0.044380  -61.260800];
cal_data.OG_0102 = [
        0.045160  -61.609900    0.044550  -61.759800
        0.044950  -61.725800    0.044480  -61.062300];

data = struct2cell(cal_data);
data = reshape(data,1,1,[]);
data = cell2mat(data);
```

`data(:,:,1)` is the same as `cal_data.OG_0100`. Etc.

You can then make a histogram for each of the values by first reshaping to a 2D matrix, where each column is a value, and each row is an observation (this requires a transpose). However, because of the very different ranges of each value, the single histogram might not be ideal. It might be better to simply draw 8 separate histograms.

```matlab
data = reshape(data,[],size(data,3)).';
hist(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am aware that the values have different ranges, I was going to do two histograms, one for columns 1 and 3, and one for column 2 and 4. They represent identical quantities.